# saml signature verification, cannot recover key exception

Tags: openssl, certificate, wso2, keystore, saml

I'm trying to implement saml authentication over ssl transport, but when the token is verified from the service provider an exception is thrown.

The problem only occurs when I use the certificates I have generated, on the countrary when I use default keystores that comes with the applicatives I'm using (WSO2) everythink works fine.

The exception is:

```
ID: [0] [ESB] [2014-10-31 17:57:03,320] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker} -  Error processing POST request for : /services/StockQuoteProxy.StockQuoteProxyHttpsSoap12Endpoint {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The signature or decryption was invalid; nested exception is: 
    java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.setFaultCodeAndThrowAxisFault(RampartReceiver.java:186)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:95)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:411)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: The signature or decryption was invalid; nested exception is: 
    java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleEncryptedKey(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:370)
    at org.apache.ws.security.saml.SAML2Util.getSAML2KeyInfo(SAML2Util.java:244)
    at org.apache.ws.security.saml.SAML2Util.getSAML2KeyInfo(SAML2Util.java:148)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:334)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.handleToken(SignatureProcessor.java:124)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:332)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:214)
    at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
    at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:311)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:121)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:38)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:763)
    at org.wso2.carbon.security.util.ServerCrypto.getPrivateKey(ServerCrypto.java:247)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.handleEncryptedKey(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:368)
    ... 18 more
```

the certificates and keystores are generated as follows:

```
server_ip=10.0.3.124

openssl req -keyout cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -days 100000 -batch -subj "/C=IT/ST=Bari/L=Molfetta/O=Exprivia/OU=Innovation Lab/CN=Exprivia Certification Authority" -passout pass:exprivia

openssl x509 -outform DER -in cacert.pem -out cacert.cert

openssl genrsa -out server.key 1024

#http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm

cp /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf myssl.cnf

echo -e "\
[req]\n\
req_extensions = v3_req\n\
\n\
[ v3_req ]\n\
\n\
# Extensions to add to a certificate request\n\
\n\
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE\n\
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment\n\
subjectAltName = @alt_names\n\
\n\
[alt_names]\n\
IP.1 = $server_ip\n\
" >> myssl.cnf

# usare IP.1 IP.2 etc per gli ip e DNS.1 etc per i nomi di dominio

openssl req -key server.key -new -out server.req -subj "/C=IT/ST=Bari/L=Molfetta/O=Exprivia/OU=Innovation Lab/CN=$server_ip" -config myssl.cnf  -days 100000 

openssl req -text -noout -in server.req > server.req.txt

echo "00" >> file.srl

openssl x509 -req -in server.req -CA cacert.pem -CAkey cakey.pem -CAserial file.srl -out server.pem  -days 100000 -extensions v3_req -extfile myssl.cnf -passin pass:exprivia

openssl x509 -text -noout -in server.pem > server.pem.txt

openssl x509 -outform DER -in server.pem -out server.cert

openssl genrsa -out client.key 1024

openssl req -key client.key -new -out client.req -subj "/C=IT/ST=Bari/L=Molfetta/O=Exprivia/OU=Innovation Lab/CN=Client" -days 100000 

openssl x509 -req -in client.req -CA cacert.pem -CAkey cakey.pem -CAserial file.srl -out client.pem  -days 100000 -passin pass:exprivia

openssl x509 -outform DER -in client.pem -out client.cert

openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.pem -inkey server.key -out server.pkcs12 -passout pass:exprivia

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server.pkcs12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore server.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass exprivia -srcstorepass exprivia -destalias server -srcalias 1 -destkeypass exprivia

keytool -import -file cacert.cert -keystore server.jks -storepass exprivia -alias cacert -noprompt

keytool -import -file client.cert -keystore server.jks -storepass exprivia -alias client -noprompt

keytool -list -v -keystore server.jks -storepass exprivia > server.txt

openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.pem -inkey client.key -out client.pkcs12 -passout pass:exprivia

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.pkcs12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore client.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass exprivia -srcstorepass exprivia -destalias client -srcalias 1 -destkeypass exprivia

keytool -import -file cacert.cert -keystore client.jks -storepass exprivia -alias cacert -noprompt

keytool -list -v -keystore client.jks -storepass exprivia > client.txt

#ora importiamo il certificato wso2

keytool -export -keystore /usr/local/wso2is-5.0.0/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks -alias wso2carbon -file wso2carbon.cert -storepass wso2carbon

#necessario per chiamare l'sts in https
keytool -import -file wso2carbon.cert -keystore client.jks -storepass exprivia -alias wso2carbon -noprompt

#necessario per decifrare il token generato da is
keytool -import -file wso2carbon.cert -keystore server.jks -storepass exprivia -alias wso2carbon -noprompt
```

and the corresponding server.jks content is

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 4 entries

Alias name: client
Creation date: 31-Oct-2014
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=Client, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Issuer: CN=Exprivia Certification Authority, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Serial number: 2
Valid from: Fri Oct 31 17:41:32 CET 2014 until: Wed Aug 15 18:41:32 CEST 2288
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  02:9B:A0:C9:F9:21:91:F5:C6:53:28:0B:C3:7E:EE:55
     SHA1: 64:D9:95:AD:BB:E8:2A:D7:81:11:B7:30:DB:EE:BE:4E:89:FE:26:4A
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 1


*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: wso2carbon
Creation date: 31-Oct-2014
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=localhost, O=WSO2, L=Mountain View, ST=CA, C=US
Issuer: CN=localhost, O=WSO2, L=Mountain View, ST=CA, C=US
Serial number: 4b7e3782
Valid from: Fri Feb 19 08:02:26 CET 2010 until: Tue Feb 13 08:02:26 CET 2035
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  02:FB:AA:5F:20:64:49:4A:27:29:55:71:83:F7:46:CD
     SHA1: 6B:F8:E1:36:EB:36:D4:A5:6E:A0:5C:7A:E4:B9:A4:5B:63:BF:97:5D
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: cacert
Creation date: 31-Oct-2014
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=Exprivia Certification Authority, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Issuer: CN=Exprivia Certification Authority, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Serial number: f8d3b3c3f00eef91
Valid from: Fri Oct 31 17:41:31 CET 2014 until: Wed Aug 15 18:41:31 CEST 2288
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  DD:D1:4B:85:BC:C0:62:AA:AA:93:9C:9C:7C:AE:69:FB
     SHA1: 20:A6:F2:1B:37:51:C2:5C:F5:98:98:B9:E5:B3:48:BC:03:0E:50:D2
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 06 44 86 D0 72 C6 ED 99   C7 EE A3 71 5A 77 C3 B4  .D..r......qZw..
0010: 7C 18 46 2D                                        ..F-
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 06 44 86 D0 72 C6 ED 99   C7 EE A3 71 5A 77 C3 B4  .D..r......qZw..
0010: 7C 18 46 2D                                        ..F-
]

]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: server
Creation date: 31-Oct-2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=10.0.3.124, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Issuer: CN=Exprivia Certification Authority, OU=Innovation Lab, O=Exprivia, L=Molfetta, ST=Bari, C=IT
Serial number: 1
Valid from: Fri Oct 31 17:41:32 CET 2014 until: Wed Aug 15 18:41:32 CEST 2288
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  7C:40:21:05:42:06:12:BC:23:7E:76:69:37:1A:8C:99
     SHA1: A8:BD:C7:41:7B:0F:98:CF:40:6B:EF:15:BF:4E:DA:F4:54:D7:38:03
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Non_repudiation
  Key_Encipherment
  Data_Encipherment
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  IPAddress: 10.0.3.124
]



*******************************************
*******************************************
```

where

- the client that asks for the token to a secure token service, uses the client.jks
- the STS uses the wso2carbon.jks and signs the token with server.cert
- the saml protected service provider, uses the server.jks

Where is the problem?

Thanks, Paolo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the exception `org.wso2.carbon.security.util.ServerCrypto.getPrivateKey` ; The Private key password that you have configured is not valid. As you are using WSO2 products, there is a `carbon.xml` file that you need to configure the keystore details such as keystore, private key password.  Could you please verify them that you have configured it properly according to the your new keystore.